# Pythonic way to check if two dictionaries have the identical set of keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, let's say I have to dictionaries:

```
d_1 = {'peter': 1, 'adam': 2, 'david': 3}
```

and

```
d_2 = {'peter': 14, 'adam': 44, 'david': 33, 'alan': 21}
```

What's the cleverest way to check whether the two dictionaries contain the same set of keys? In the example above, it should return `False` because `d_2` contains the `'alan'` key, which `d_1` doesn't.

I am not interested in checking that the associated values match. Just want to make sure if the keys are same.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can get the keys for a dictionary with `dict.keys()`.

You can turn this into a set with `set(dict.keys())`

You can compare sets with `==`

To sum up:

```
set(d_1.keys()) == set(d_2.keys())
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: True, you don't need the keys, but if you don't use sets very often I'd say that the behaviour of set(dictionary) is non-obvious.  Does anyone know if using keys introduces a performance hit?

Comment: @xorsyst: in Python 2 `iter(a_dict)` returns an iterator, `a_dict.keys()` returns a list; therefore, `set(d_1.keys())` incurs the creation and destruction of a temporary list of the dictionary keys. In Python 3, they're equivalent.

Comment: @xorsyst: what's non-obvious with that behaviour? What else should be done when using set(some_dict)? It is also the same behaviour when you do list(some_dict), which also returns a list of the keys

Comment: @Joschua: If you are familiar with list(some_dict), then I agree set(some_dict) should be pretty obvious.  But to me, it's not at all obvious that these would work the way they do.  My first expectation is that list(some_dict) would be a list of (key, value) tuples.  I agree that returning just the keys is a useful behaviour, but I wouldn't say it was "obvious".

Comment: Why do you convert the `dict_keys` elements to `set`s?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye because in Python 2 (see the age of the answer), d_1.keys() returns a list in an arbitrary order, so you need to convert to a set to get a fair comparison. You could also use sorted() on the keys, but that's slower.

Comment: `dict.keys()` already returns a `set` like object which supports all the `set` operations. Therefore, calling `set(dict.keys())` is redundant.

Comment: @xyres As per the above comment, this answer is 12 years old and so is appropriate for Python 2 and 3. If you are only using Python 3, the set isn't needed.

Answer (score 55):

In Python2,

```
set(d_1) == set(d_2)
```

In Python3, you can do this which may be a tiny bit more efficient than creating sets

```
d1.keys() == d2.keys()
```

although the Python2 way would work too

Answer (score 13):

- In Python 3, [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a "[view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)" that can be used like a set.  This is much more efficient than constructing a separate set.

  ```
  d_1.keys() == d_2.keys()
  ```
- In Python 2.7, [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) does the same thing.

  ```
  d_1.viewkeys() == d_2.viewkeys()
  ```
- In Python 2.6 and below, you have to construct a set of the keys of each dict.

  ```
  set(d_1) == set(d_2)
  ```

  Or you can iterate over the keys yourself for greater memory efficiency.

  ```
  len(d_1) == len(d_2) and all(k in d_2 for k in d_1)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> not set(d_1).symmetric_difference(d_2)
False
>>> not set(d_1).symmetric_difference(dict.fromkeys(d_1))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check for [symmetric difference](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) (new set with elements in either s or t but not both):

```
set(d_1.keys()).symmetric_difference(set(d_2.keys()))
```

But a shorter way it to just compare the sets:

```
set(d_1) == set(d_2)
```

Answer (score -2):

A quick option (not sure if its the most optimal)

```
len(set(d_1.keys()).difference(d_2.keys())) == 0
```

Comment: SilentGhost's reply will return false if the keys are the same but the values are different

Comment: Checking for len == 0 is probably the most unpythonic thing.

Comment: @Alex Nope.  Try it yourself.