# Check that Python dicts have same shape and keys

Tags: python, dictionary

For single layer dicts like `x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` the problem is easy and answered on SO ([Pythonic way to check if two dictionaries have the identical set of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210832/pythonic-way-to-check-if-two-dictionaries-have-the-identical-set-of-keys)) but what about nested dicts?

For example, `y = {'a': {'c': 3}, 'b': {'d': 4}}` has keys `'a'` and `'b'` but I want to compare its shape to another nested dict structure like `z = {'a': {'c': 5}, 'b': {'d': 6}}` which has the same shape and keys (different values is fine) as `y`. `w = {'a': {'c': 3}, 'b': {'e': 4}}` would have keys `'a'` and `'b'` but on the next layer in it differs from `y` because `w['b']` has key `'e'` while `y['b']` has key `'d'`.

Want a short/simple function of two arguments `dict_1` and `dict_2` and return `True` if they have same shape and key as described above, and `False` otherwise.

Comment: I see someone voted to close this as unclear, so I'd like to go on the record as saying I find nothing unclear about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This provides a copy of both dictionaries stripped of any non-dictionary values, then compares them:

```
def getshape(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k:getshape(d[k]) for k in d}
    else:
        # Replace all non-dict values with None.
        return None

def shape_equal(d1, d2):
    return getshape(d1) == getshape(d2)
```

Comment: I wish there was an equally elegant way that didn't require creating an entire shadow structure for both data structures.

Comment: You could recursively compare them (similar to what @CCKx did), but I find it simpler to express custom comparisons as comparisons between canonicalized representations, rather than coding the actual comparison logic myself.

Comment: (As an example, this is kind of the difference between using `sort(cmp=...)` and `sort(key=...)`; I find the latter to be unambiguously more clear in the majority of instances).

Comment: I posted my own approach. Someone should profile our two approaches, determine which is faster.

Answer (score 7):

I liked nneonneo's answer, and it should be relatively fast, but I want something that didn't create extra unnecessary data structures (I've been learning about memory fragmentation in Python). This may or may not be as fast or faster.

(EDIT: Spoiler!)

> Faster by a decent enough margin to make it preferable in all cases, see the other analysis answer.

But if dealing with lots and lots of these and having memory problems, it is likely to be preferable to do it this way.

#### Implementation

This should work in Python 3, maybe 2.7 if you translate `keys` to `viewkeys`, definitely not 2.6. It relies on the set-like view of the keys that dicts have:

```
def sameshape(d1, d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict):
        if isinstance(d2, dict):
            # then we have shapes to check
            return (d1.keys() == d2.keys() and
                    # so the keys are all the same
                    all(sameshape(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1.keys()))
                    # thus all values will be tested in the same way.
        else:
            return False # d1 is a dict, but d2 isn't
    else:
        return not isinstance(d2, dict) # if d2 is a dict, False, else True.
```

*Edit* updated to reduce redundant type check, now even more efficient.

#### Testing

To check:

```
print('expect false:')
print(sameshape({'foo':{'bar':{None:None}}}, {'foo':{'bar':{None: {} }}}))
print('expect true:')
print(sameshape({'foo':{'bar':{None:None}}}, {'foo':{'bar':{None:'foo'}}}))
print('expect false:')
print(sameshape({'foo':{'bar':{None:None}}}, {'foo':{'bar':{None:None, 'baz':'foo'}}}))
```

Prints:

```
expect false:
False
expect true:
True
expect false:
False
```

Answer (score 0):

To profile the two currently existing answers, first lets import `timeit`:

```
import timeit
```

Now we need to setup the code:

```
setup = '''
import copy

def getshape(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k:getshape(d[k]) for k in d}
    else:
        # Replace all non-dict values with None.
        return None

def nneo_shape_equal(d1, d2):
    return getshape(d1) == getshape(d2)

def aaron_shape_equal(d1,d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict) and isinstance(d2, dict):
        return (d1.keys() == d2.keys() and 
                all(aaron_shape_equal(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1.keys()))
    else:
        return not (isinstance(d1, dict) or isinstance(d2, dict))

class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

d = Vividict()

d['foo']['bar']
d['foo']['baz']
d['fizz']['buzz']
d['primary']['secondary']['tertiary']['quaternary']

d0 = copy.deepcopy(d)
d1 = copy.deepcopy(d)
d1['primary']['secondary']['tertiary']['extra']
# d == d0 is True
# d == d1 is now False!
'''
```

And now let's test the two options out, first with Python 3.3!

```
>>> timeit.repeat('nneo_shape_equal(d0, d); nneo_shape_equal(d1,d)', setup=setup)
[36.784881490981206, 36.212246977956966, 36.29759863798972]
```

And it looks like my solution takes 2/3rd to 3/4th the time, making it more than 1.25 times as fast.

```
>>> timeit.repeat('aaron_shape_equal(d0, d); aaron_shape_equal(d1,d)', setup=setup)
[26.838892214931548, 26.61037168605253, 27.170253590098582]
```

And on a version of Python 3.4 (an alpha) that I compiled myself:

```
>>> timeit.repeat('nneo_shape_equal(d0, d); nneo_shape_equal(d1,d)', setup=setup)
[272.5629618819803, 273.49581588001456, 270.13374400604516]
>>> timeit.repeat('aaron_shape_equal(d0, d); aaron_shape_equal(d1,d)', setup=setup)
[214.87033835891634, 215.69223327597138, 214.85333003790583]
```

Still about the same ratio. The time difference between the two is likely because I self-compiled 3.4 without optimizations.

Thanks to all readers!

Comment: This doesn't actually surprise me. Making objects will usually be more expensive than not making objects. I wonder if perhaps you should try this out without using a custom class.

Comment: no, rerunning the tests, ran the first time with Python 2.7, which I didn't adjust the code for, this time ran with 3.3. I'll do it with 3.4 too.

Comment: 3.4 finally finished. That took forever!

Comment: Yeah, something wrong with your 3.4, I'd guess you built a debug version (that is PY_DEBUG)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah, but nearly same ratio of results apparently. PY_DEBUG you say? I'll have to look into it. Would be nice if someone else would verify the results, though. Thanks in advance to whoever does so.

Comment: Btw, isinstance is one of the slowest ops, you might want to store in variable...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer that allows using an ANY. This is useful if you only want to check a certain level deep.

```py
ANY = "ANY"

def shape_equal(d1, d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict) and isinstance(d2, dict):
        for k in d1:
            if k not in d2:
                return False
            if not shape_equal(d1[k], d2[k]):
                return False
            
        for k in d2:
            if k not in d1:
                return False
        return True
    elif isinstance(d1, dict) and d2 == ANY:
        return True
    elif not isinstance(d1, dict) and not isinstance(d2, dict):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then to test

```py
assert shape_equal({"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}) == True
assert shape_equal({"a": 1, "b": {"foo": "bar"}}, {"a": 1, "b": {
    "foo": 33
}}) == True
assert shape_equal({"a": 1, "b": {"foo": "bar"}}, {"a": 1, "b": ANY}) == True
assert shape_equal({"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": {"foo": "bar"}}) == False
```