# Extract dictionary data which match with other dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've two dictionaries one original & the other reference. And I want to match reference dict keys with original dict keys and extract all those keys, values from original which are present in reference.
For example

```
original_dict = {
    'a': {
        '1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    'b': {
        '1': {
            'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    },
    'c': {
        '3': [1]
    }
}
```

And a reference dictionary

```
reference_dict = {
    'a': {
        '2': [1, 2, 3]
    },
    'b': {
        '1': {
            'A': []
        }
    },
    'c': {
        '3': []
    }
}
```

And this is the extracted dictionary.

```
extracted_dict = {
    'b': {
        '1': {
            'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    },
    'c': {
        '3': [1]
    }
}
```

Here you might have noticed that I don't care about values of reference dict. All I want is the values of original dict.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @abhilb I've found to check if two dictionary are equal. But the next step I want is to extract those same keys
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192748/check-that-python-dicts-have-same-shape-and-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to accomplish this:

```py
def merge(value_dict, key_dict):
    ret = {}
    for key, subdict in key_dict.items():
        if key in value_dict:
            if not isinstance(value_dict[key], dict):
                # we found a value so don't keep recursing
                ret[key] = value_dict[key]
            else:
                # found another dict so merge subdicts
                merged = merge(value_dict[key], subdict)
                if len(merged) > 0:
                    ret[key] = merged
    return ret

merge(original_dict, reference_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if I understand your question 100% but this might be a solution.
we use relevant `keys` and put them in a list to use them on a `.update() dict`

```
new_lst = []

for i in original_dict.keys():
    new_lst.append(original_dict[i])
reference_dict.clear()
for i in new_lst:
    reference_dict.update(i)

print(reference_dict)
```

Comment: Ahhh! This is extracting data. But there is a little problem. It is ignoring the most parent keys.