# How to return a boolean to check if elements in two dicts are the same in python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {
    'Argentina': ['Buenos Aires'],
    'Bangladesh': ['Dhaka'],
    'Brazil': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro']

dict2 = {
    1392685764: 'Tokyo', 1356226629: 'Mumbai', 1156073548: 'Shanghai',
    1484247881: 'Mexico City', 1156237133: 'Guangzhou', 1818253931: 'Cairo',
    1156228865: 'Beijing', 1840034016: 'New York', 1643318494: 'Moscow',
    1764068610: 'Bangkok', 1050529279: 'Dhaka', 1032717330: 'Buenos Aires'}
```

I would like to check that the nested values in dict1 have any elements in common with values in dict2. I've been doing this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210832/pythonic-way-to-check-if-two-dictionaries-have-the-identical-set-of-keys):

```
def f(d1, d2, id, country):
    return set(d1.values()) == set(d2.values())
```

So, when the function is called with arguments dict1, dict2, country=Argentina and id=1032717330 returns True.

But the result is always an TypeError. Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: That should get an error, not return false, since you can't put lists into a set. You need to flatten the lists in `dict1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "same"? Lists are obviously not equal to strings, and the number of values isn't even equal here (assuming these two are supposed to match). Do you want to check that the *nested* values in `dict1` have *any* elements in common with `dict2`? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: What are the `id` and `country` parameters for?

Comment: Turns out you question was very different from what you originaly wrote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the first dictionary values makes flatern,

```
def f(d1, d2):
     '''d1 values should be list'''
     return set([i for sublist in d1.values() for i in sublist]) == set(d2.values())
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: f(dict1, dict2)
Out[1]: False
```

**EDIT**
On your reversed requirements, you have to do this. You need to check the `d2.value` is exists in `d1.value`

```
def f(d1, d2, id, country):
    return d2.get(id) in d1.get(country)


f(dict1, dict2, 1032717330, 'Argentina')
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `dict1` has lists as values, so you need to "chain" them into a single list first. You cat try something like this:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*dict1.values())) == set(dict2.values())
```

It's unclear how you want to use id and country, so I've left this out of the function.

Comment: I want to use id and country to call the function with arguments d1=dict1, d2=dict2, country=Argentina and id=1032717330 in order to return True.

Answer (score -1):

Both dictionaries and sets are unordered which is probably why you're getting different results. Assuming Python, you could do something like this:

```
def has_same_values(d1, d2):
    values1 = []
    values2 = []
    for key in d1.keys():
        values1.extend(d1[key])
    for key in d2.keys():
        values2.extend(d2[key])
    return values1.sort() == values2.sort()
```